# How to add a variable in a Javascript object who's changing in a for

Tags: javascript, variables, object

```
Subs.find({ }).forEach(function(div){
 var sub_type = div.type ;
 var sub_TO = div.text ;
 var man = div.arn;
 var obj = {man: []};
 obj.man.push({"type": sub_type, "TO" :sub_TO});
 var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
 console.log(json);
})
```

here is my problem I want `man` who is in `obj` to be a variable and change each time the `forEach()` runs and i don't understand why when i log the `obj` i see man instead of the value my variable.

An other question. if it is posible to use a variable for the `man` how should i do the line `obj.man.push({"type": sub_type, "TO" :sub_TO});` ?

Comment: See the linked question's answers, but use `man` instead of `myObj.action1` et. al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use new initializer syntax that lets you use an expression for the key. Use square brackets for this:

```
var obj = {[man]: []};
```

Or for legacy browsers, create the object first, then use the brackets to evaluate the expression.

```
var obj = {};
obj[man] = [];
```

Then use the typical square brackets when accessing the property.

```
obj[man].push({"type": sub_type, "TO" :sub_TO});
```